# syntax for wstool set?

Tags: ros, syntax, catkin, wstool, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to specify a version of a catkin package to install (--version -new) how do you do this?

```
wstool set rosconsole_bridge https://github.com/ros/rosconsole_bridge.git --git --version-new -y
```

or

```
wstool set rosconsole_bridge https://github.com/ros/rosconsole_bridge.git --git --version-groovy -y
```

or is there something I'm doing wrong in my syntax?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64988/syntax-for-wstool-set?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
wstool set rosconsole_bridge --git https://github.com/ros/rosconsole_bridge.git -v groovy
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4